# Cannot get the account id if connected to Mumbai RPC testnet

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I have added MATIC Mumbai Testnet RPC and required info using this : https://docs.matic.network/docs/develop/remix to metamask. That is added the network to it.

Now I am using web3 and calling

```
    const web3 = new Web3('https://rpc-mumbai.matic.today');
    const network = await web3.eth.net.getNetworkType();
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
   
    console.log(accounts[0])
```

I am getting undefined in the console.

whereas if I go for

```
    const web3 = new Web3('http:localhost:7545');
    const network = await web3.eth.net.getNetworkType();
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
   
    console.log(accounts[0])
```

which is my local network it works and I get the account address

I feel like I am missing something, Can anyone help ?